# submit all input elements on a page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is there an easy way to submit all input elements on a page?

I have a very customisable page where the user can add and remove rows from multiple tables. The rows contain various different input elements. Do I have to put each table inside a form and then on submit have javascript to submit all the forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit *all* input elements, it's sufficient to have only one `<form>` that encircles them all. Calling `form.submit()` from JS or with a classic submit button then catches all input fields.

If you want a dynamic selection by the user, let her put inputs *inside* the form element for submission and *outside* to keep them where they are. This can be achieved with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just put one form on the page that contains all your tables and inputs and submit that – you cannot submit more than one form at a time.